# How to create submenu based on content type and taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, nodes

I would like to create a submenu that lists items based on content type and taxonomy.  Here's the setup.

```
Shop for a Car [Basic Page]
    Financing Options for cars [Basic Page]
       loan 1 [Content Type: Loan / Taxonomy: Car, Home]
       loan 2 [Content Type: Loan / Taxonomy: Car]
       loan 3 [Content Type: Loan / Taxonomy: Car, Home]
Shop for a Home [Basic Page]
    Financing Options for homes [Basic Page]
       loan 1 [Content Type: Loan / Taxonomy Car, Home]
       loan 3 [Content Type: Loan / Taxonomy Car, Home]
```

Notice that loan 1 and loan 3 appear under two different parents.  I know I can create this menu structure manually using NodeSymlinks. In that case the Taxonomy terms are not needed.  However, I would like to generate the menu automatically using the terms for a particular content type.  I looked into the taxonomy menu module but it only allows one parent and it lists the taxonomy tag rather than the items tagged.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use views to create your links for the content types and then use the views field view module http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view as a field on that to show the child taxonomy terms associated to the content type.

Comment: Thanks but how does this integrate with the menu?

Comment: Well I never use taxonomy terms as menu items.  It causes nothing but problems.  Taxonomy is used to filter/group content, not for menu items.  But by using views and some template magic, you can rewrite your output as a menu like you are needing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Rules. This module: http://drupal.org/project/menu_rules adds some actions to rules. One of them is to create a menu item for a node. You can create two rules:

1.Rule:

Event: Create a node | Update a node

Condition: Content type is "Loan" | Taxonomy term is "Home"

Action: Update a menu item for node (there is a checkbox to create the menu item if it doesnt exist) -> Select "Financing Options for homes" for parent menu item

2.Rule:

Event: Create a node | Update a node

Condition: Content type is "Loan" | Taxonomy term is "Car"

Action: Update a menu item for node (there is a checkbox to create the menu item if it doesnt exist) -> Select "Financing Options for cars" for parent menu item